# Getting Wrong Answer or Time Limited Exceeded in a dynamic programming problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve [TRT](https://www.spoj.com/problems/TRT/) problem with Python3 and getting WA for this code:

```
from sys import stdin,stdout
try:

    def recur(a,l,r,cnt,ans, dp):
        # print(l,r,cnt,ans)
        if l>r:
            return ans
        if dp[l][r] !=-1:
            return dp[l][r]
        prev_ans=ans
        ans=max(ans, recur(a,l+1,r,cnt+1,prev_ans + cnt*a[l],dp))
        ans=max(ans, recur(a,l,r-1,cnt+1,prev_ans + cnt*a[r],dp))
        dp[l][r]=max(dp[l][r],ans)
        return ans

    n=int(stdin.readline())
    a=[]
    dp=[[-1 for x in range(n+5)] for z in range(n+5)]
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(int(stdin.readline()))

    stdout.write(str(recur(a,0,n-1,1,0,dp)))
except Excpetion as e:
    print(e)
```

As per one suggestion in comment, I tried changing dp array length to 2010, but then I got TLE. I tried creating a TC that fails, but couldn't find any, It would be great if someone can suggest me something.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that applies your algorithm in C and gets accepted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

int f(int A[], int n, int l, int r, int dp[][2000]){
  int k = n - r + l;

  if (l == r)
    return A[l] * k;

  if (dp[l][r])
    return dp[l][r];

  return dp[l][r] = max(A[l] * k + f(A, n, l+1, r, dp), A[r] * k + 
 f(A, n, l, r-1, dp));
}

int main(void){
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int A[n];
  int dp[2000][2000] = {0};

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);

  printf("%d", f(A, n, 0, n-1, dp));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution...but I am still wondering why it fails in Python

Comment: @PratikGandhi I don't know too much about it but it might be the overhead associated with recursion in Python. Python also has a low recursion depth limit but I would think that would have resulted in an error rather than TLE.